STM32 USB DFU Custom Software
I'm writing a QT Software (for Windows) for flashing new firmware onto STM32 microcontrollers, using the STM32 internal bootloader.
This software should use TTL-UART and USB as methods to "speak" with the bootloader.
I successfully implemented the UART bootloader, but I found myself stuck when starting the USB part.
I could use stm32cubeprogrammer's dll or I could write code from scratch.
CubeProgrammer_API.dll brings a lot of unneeded things with it.
If I were to write the code from scratch to implement the few functions I need, what should I do?
The device is listed as "STM32  BOOTLOADER" under "USB Devices".
The protocol used is described in this document: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3156-usb-dfu-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf
What I'm missing is how to implement it in my SW.
5 days of googling and I still can't understand what to do. Could you give me some pointers?
(I'm currently reading this https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/DFU_1.1.pdf)
Thank you.

First you need to find out what USB device it is. If you don't find any documented, you can use Wireshark to watch the USB connection. Depending on the result, the next steps vary.

Kind of depends on the host system for the PC software. Doing port I/O manually is quite different between Windows and Linux.
